# Test JSF using selenium, element not found

Tags: selenium, web-applications, jsf-2

Trying to test JSF web app using selenium: record and play. recording: no problem. But playback, input element not found error. The input text field id is foo:bar:inputText. In the Selenium IDE, the find command can find the element, but playback complains the element not found.

Does Selenium support JSF? JSF element id is like aaa:bbb:ccc:ddd? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "selenium" instead of "solenium"?

Comment: Yes. my typo. selenium. In jQuery, find element by JSF element id, the id needs to be escaped because of special char. Not sure if selenium supports JSF id.

Comment: `:` is a valid character for id's, so I don't see why selenium shouldn't support it.